# Using the AForge Genetic lib to decide spawn composition of a wave in a tower defence game

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, aforge

I am trying to use the GA to create stronger waves of enemies in a tower defence game similar to plants vs zombies. Each population represents a wave and each chromosome represents an enemy(1011 = basic enemy, 1111 = enemy 2 etc.) I am using the AForge library, however i was wondering if its possible to set the initial population instead of it being randomly generated and how I can set the values for x and y (distance and damage) for each chromosome in a population. I am also not entirely sure as to what the Range represents.
Sorry if im missing something simple or if I am misunderstanding how it works, this is what I have so far, thanks:

```
 public class UserFunction : OptimizationFunction2D
{
    private double distanceMax = 1;
    private double damageMax = 1;
    private double w1 = 1;
    private double w2 = 1;


    public UserFunction() :
        base(new Range(0, 100), new Range(0, 100)) { }

    public override double OptimizationFunction(double distance, double damage)
    {
        return (w1*distance/distanceMax) + (w2*damage/damageMax);
    }
}

class RunProgram
{
    private Population[] populationArray = new Population[5];
    private UserFunction userFunction = new UserFunction();
    private BinaryChromosome chromosome = new BinaryChromosome(4);
    private int popSize = 20;
    private double mutateRate = 0.3;
    private double damage;
    private double distance;
    private double limit = 100;


    public RunProgram()
    {
        Pop();
    }

    private void Pop()
    {
           // create genetic population
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            populationArray[i] = new Population(popSize,
                                chromosome,
                                userFunction,
                                new RouletteWheelSelection());
        }

        foreach (var pop in populationArray)
        {
            pop.MutationRate = mutateRate;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            foreach (var pop in populationArray)
            {
                pop.RunEpoch();                    
            }                                                           
        }


        Array.Sort(populationArray, delegate(Population population1, Population population2) {
            return population1.FitnessAvg.CompareTo(population2.FitnessAvg);
            });


        EnemyList(populationArray[4]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void EnemyList(Population population)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < popSize; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enemy "+ i +" is: "+population[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all populations are approaching to an optimal wave. So representing a wave  with population is useless unless each wave has unique conditions.